# To create control file for loading data into table

Tags: scripting

I have 1 data file where in 1 column some data is present with prefix 'D' like 'D1234'.I need to load those data into table without including D.like in table data should be '1234'.Need to remove prefix D and load the data.Is there any way to do like this.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what software or coding language do you want to use?

Comment: I need to put that in my control file(.ctl) so that from data file (.dat) i can extract the data in a column and can load into a table without the prefix.